# Vnc Server does not start on Fedora Core 11?

Tags: linux, fedora, vnc

I am trying to get VNC server on a fedora core 11 box and can't get it to run. 
The log contents are below. Any ideas what should be done here?

Couldn't open RGB_DB '/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/rgb'

Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.3 - built Oct 15 2008 12:55:42
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40201000, The XFree86 Project, Inc

Wed Sep 16 17:45:43 2009
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/, removing from list!

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
vncconfig: unable to open display "vivekian.com:1"
xrdb: Connection refused
xrdb: Can't open display 'vivekian.com:1'
xmodmap:  unable to open display 'vivekian.com:1'
$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server.

### Update :

I am using RealVNC - Downloaded the package from its website and unzipped it. Copied the binary images to /usr/bin.

Comment: Which VNC package are you using ?  The Fedora project switched to TigerVNC with Fedora 11, but it looks as if you may be using something different.  Can you indicatehow you installed your VNC package as well ?

Comment: I am using RealVNC - Downloaded the package from its website and unzipped it. Copied the scripts from the RealVNC folder to /usr/bin. 
I have a feeling it has probably overwritten TigerVNC - since its scripts were of the same name ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking around the Web for references to your error message, I couldn't find any obvious solutions, but I think it may be that the RealVNC package isn't compatible with the X libraries used in Fedora 11.  I'd recommend uninstalling RealVNC and trying TigerVNC (installed via yum), as this will have been tested to be compatible with Fedora 11.

Comment: Agreed, you're almost always better off going with the packaged version of a piece of software rather than rolling your own.